# jquery display block / none

Tags: jquery

hi as i am new to this jquery could any one help me with this 
i would like to show the div and hide the dive after trasnsition here is the script

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
            animIn = function () {
                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 300);
            };

        if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({

                    left: -$this.width()
                }, 300, animIn);
            });
        } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            animIn();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if using the id for div then

```
$('#dividhere').attr('display','block') //to show
$('#dividhere').attr('display','none') //to hide
```

if using the class for div then

```
$('.divclasshere').attr('display','block') //to show
$('.divclasshere').attr('display','none') //to hide
```

Comment: @M1K1O sorry i didn't change the hide part after copy

Comment: How can it works ? you must change `block` to `none` in the **hide** row.

Comment: something like this
            jQuery(function($) {
            
                $('a.panel').click(function() {
                    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                        $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
                        animIn = function () {
                            $target.addClass('active')
       $('.panel').attr('display','block')
       .show().css({
                                left: -($target.width())
                            }).animate({
                                left: 0
                            }, 300);

Comment: here i have created a fiddle whats happening is its inside a content and when it slides out it stays there only and the next div comes in i want the prev div to have display none so that it is not seen

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the multiple division (division inside division) in your form then you have to find the id of child div in the parent division like this.

```
$("#parentDiv").find("#childDiv").css("display", "block");      
$("#parentDiv").find("#childDiv").css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try show and hide in jquery,

```
 $('element').show();

 $('element').hide();
```